# How to access control inside of a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, code-behind

How can I access my btnViewTable from code-behind? Specifically to be able to set the visibility on or off, or even remove it. I've looked at GetTemplateChild as well as FindName, but have been unable to access the button. I can manage to obtain a reference to the ControlTemplate, but can't get any further than that.

```
<Grid x:Name="pnlSearch" Background="White">
<TextBlock x:Name="txtSearchResults" />
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="grdResults">
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FoundFieldName}"/>
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
<sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="btnViewTable"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = (Button)DataGrid.Template.FindName("btnViewTable", "DataGridControl");
button.Click += //Do something;
```

Where DataGrid/DataGridControl is the actual DataGridControl

Comment: doing that gives me the error "System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindName' and no extension method 'FindName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I currently don't have DataGrid in my machine to test it out. The idea is there, can you try digging into the DataGrid and look for DataGridRowGroupHeader and probably loop through it and once you get one of the item, it should have the Template property where you can access it and do FindName

Answer (score 0):

To handle parts of the template, from outside of the control, is always a not-so-good idea.

For a quick fix, I'd go with:

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding SomeVisibilityProperty}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                <Grid
                    <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="btnViewTable"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
```

Where `SomeVisibilityProperty` is a property in the data context. Might need to use `RelativeSource`.

For a "true" fix, I'd define an attached property. Set this property to bind to the same property on parent grid and then have the button to bind to the property on `DataGridRowGroupHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just referring to a property in codebehind:

http://www.jayway.com/2011/05/17/bind-from-xaml-to-property-defined-in-code-behind/